# Custom loginform when using windows authentication

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-deployment-project

Is it possible to have a custom loginpage when using windows authentication on your IIS site? I guess I need to mix form+windows authentication to make this happen?

Comment: What "form+windows authentication" are you talking about?

Comment: why is my question beeing voted down? What is unclear? I taged it with IIS, anyone using that should have no problem understanding the authentication context.

Comment: Nope, it remains unclear. If you do use IIS and have a lot of knowledge on it, then you should know why I commented above in that way. I also commented on the answer below which if you read you should learn more about what I meant.

Comment: okey, so the answer is YES, they can be mixed.. _Windows and forms authentication can mix, and in several ways (mvolo.com/… is one of such)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to implement a custom login for site using windows authentication. Windows auth happens before your code runs so it is either using Windows auth or use forms authentication, you can't do both, and authentication via Windows doesn't mean you are authenticated via Forms auth, and logging in with Forms auth doesn't mean you are Windows authenticated.  To validate that you are logged in from forms auth, code has to run...but for the code to run you first have to be validated via Windows auth.  You're basically using two different auth mechanisms thinking they are compatible or equivalent when they're not. windows authentication works on different TCP/IP layer and form authentication works on Internet layer vs Application layer and there is also different type of windows authentication are available like Kerberos version with NTLM fallback.The windows authentication form is built-in into the browser.

For workaround you could try:

•   Implement a custom membership provider, where you can use, when needed, an impersonation/delegation mechanism

•   Implement a single sign-on architecture, using, for example, ADFS.

Regards,
Jalpa.

Comment: This answer contains incorrect pieces, so future readers are warned. 1) Windows authentication is still an HTTP layer thing, similar to forms authentication. They just use different mechanisms. 2) Windows and forms authentication can mix, and in several ways (http://mvolo.com/iis-70-twolevel-authentication-with-forms-authentication-and-windows-authentication/ is one of such), and that's why I commented above and asked what exactly was being asked.